# How to hide title bar of NSWindow but close and minimize button should be visible?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, titlebar

I want to hide the title bar of NSWindow. But the close button and minimize button of NSWindow should be visible. Also, the window should be drag anywhere on the screen after hiding the title bar.

I have referred to the below link.
[Xcode & Swift - Window without title bar but with close, minimize and resize buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250762/xcode-swift-window-without-title-bar-but-with-close-minimize-and-resize-but)

But this is not working for me.

I want to make exactly the same window as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32208877/2227743

Comment: I got the solution.